# Why my laptop got buzzing sound?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, noise

So my laptop starts having buzzing sound ([listen here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1umPuM57EcK1ObZRBEZoNzMkMzaddMFHx)) no matter I close all the applications or run lightweight Linux (`Arch Linux`) to see if it's CPU's sound it's still buzzing. Recently the glue of my laptop's stand has ripped off (see image below), I don't know if this causing my laptop buzzing (maybe it fall inside), anyone can help me out is it CPU issue or fan's issue or dust inside or other issues?

[image: laptop's stand glue (image)]

Comment: Sounds like the fan is hitting a wire. However, I don't know how we can know for sure. Take it apart and look or take it to a computer shop and ask them to.

Comment: @Dave Then will it be fine if I continue using the laptop and send to to shop when I have time or should I shutdown it now?

Comment: I can't answer that. As I wrote, I think it sounds like the fan hitting the wire but I doubt any one can verify it without seeing it. Personally, the risk is yours. I suggest turning it off just in case.

Comment: Looks like your fan bearing is going bad. Had a couple of them gone bad on me on my old Black Macbook. Just replace it, clean it and apply new thermal paste

Answer (score 0):

There are really only 2 components that can make a buzzing sound. Fan & hard drive. Just from taking a look at the photo you sent, I would lean towards dirty/failing fan.

Listening to the sound, that sounds like something is caught in the fan.

The glue is really just another matter that most likely isn't related, but could be from the system overheating due to low cooling efficiency.

Start with the simple thing, get a can of compress air, blow the dust out and see if it helps any. If not, you may need to have someone look at it if you feel uncomfortable opening the bottom of your laptop.

Comment: Will it because I'm playing with Monero miner recently, since I'm using CPU miner?

Comment: @Munucial Not really. Only in the fact that you are using the system more the wear was bound to happen at some point regardless.